# Mysql Select Sum but last three records

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, greatest-n-per-group, sql-limit

I have table with fields Customer date and amount
I want to sum Amount grouped by customer except the last two amounts of every customer  by date
sample data

```
 customer     date               amount
  a           2020-10-1             100
  a           2020-10-2             150
  a           2020-10-3             30
  a           2020-10-4             20
  b           2020-10-1             1
  b           2020-10-5             13
  b           2020-10-7             50
  b           2020-10-9             18
```

desired result

```
  Customer    Amount
   A          150
   B           14
```

something like

```
select Customer , 
SUM(amount- last 2 amount)
From TableA
Group By Customer
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: i added a sample data and result desired

Comment: @BeidreAhmed: presumably, the total for customer A should be 250 rather than 150.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses window functions, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select customer, sum(amount) total_amount
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by customer order by date desc) rn
    from tablea a
) a
where rn > 2
group by customer
```

In earlier versions, an alternative uses a correlated subquery that returns the third latest date per customer for filtering:

```
select customer, sum(amount) total_amount
from tablea a
where date <= (select a1.date from tablea a1 where a1.customer = a.customer order by a1.date desc limit 2, 1)
group by customer
```

Comment: this gives the error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by customer order by date desc) rn
    from table t' at line 3  @GMB

Comment: @BeidreAhmed: you are running a pre-8.0 version of MySQL. I edited my answer with an alternative.